# Flutter Android Firebase PhoneAuth error: INVALID_APP_ID

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing phone OTP authentication in flutter using firebase.
I managed to get it working on iOS, but on Android I get this error (when trying to send the OTP):

```
E/FirebaseAuth(15076): [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_APP_ID 400
E/zzf     (15076): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_APP_ID ]]- calling backend without app verification
E/FirebaseAuth(15076): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
```

On iOS everything works fine, I can proceed to enter captcha and after that the SMS is sent to the device.
But Android version seems to not pass some security checks.

I've tried entering the SHA1 and SHA256 to the Firebase Console and enabling Device Verification API in Google Cloud, but it doesn't help.

Comment: hello, were you able to fix this? because I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @kandykane, hi! Yes, I fixed this issue, but I don't quite remember how :) Here's the repo: https://github.com/k0marov/messenger-flutter

Comment: oh well my luck.. i think all your firebase keys and files will be private and not on github.. please let me know if you remember. thank you !